# AVCaptureSession interruption event occurs when Twilio video camera.startCapture(...) is called

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, twilio-video

Before integrating Twilio into our application we have set up audio/video recording which saves 5s length video chunks to local storage and then uploads to the remote server.
Everything is classic here: first, we have `var videoSession: AVCaptureSession`. Then we add *input* and *output* and at the same time setting `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` to the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` instance with `setSampleBufferDelegate(...)` method call.
The following is easy, we just need to handle the following delegate method:

```
captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

This gives as possibility to capture and save media chunks. Optionally we have also a video preview view setup with a *video session* object.
The problem started to occur when we decided to integrate Twilio video into our app for video meetings. When the following Twilio method call occurs for a `CameraSource` object
`camera.startCapture(...)` then we receive session interruption event with `.videoDeviceInUseByAnotherClient` reason and my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` `captureOutput()` method is stoping to work. If I restart `AVCaptureSession` then `captureOutput()` is starting to work again but Twilio video is stopping to cast a video. This is a pretty complex situation since we are not applicable to change our video recording code based on pure *AVFoundation* implementation but at the same time, we should provide a video meeting feature.
As soon as I could understand, a video session can have only one owner, and switching them drops the current owner. I am totally unable to find any solution as I have tried to find anything in Twilio documentation with no luck. Probably I miss something, maybe there is some way to use the existing session to broadcast the user's video?

Any help is really appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: You can only capture once from a video source at a time, so you will need to find a way to share the video track. I'm not an iOS developer, so I don't have an answer for you, but I'd look into whether you can clone the resource to use in your recording and the video call, or if you can use the existing capture stream you have to initialise a `TVILocalVideoTrack` with.

Comment: @philnash that's a great idea and feels very natural, but it seems I can't find any constructor for `TVILocalVideoTrack` taking existing capture stream. I'm a little bit surprised that Twilio devs didn't add such a great option, although it might be possible that I didn’t search well enough. Thank you very much!